# Notation: Vectors in a Matrix

Tags: notation

In my lecturer's notes, he made use of the notation $$\begin{pmatrix}|&|&|\\\mathbf u&\mathbf v&\mathbf w\\|&|&|\end{pmatrix}$$
to denote a matrix which is made up of the vectors $\mathbf u$, $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$. He states in the notes that it is not a standardised notation, but he used it for convenience. He used a similar notation for covectors:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-~\mathbf a~-\\-~\mathbf b~-\\-~\mathbf c~-\end{pmatrix}$$
Has anyone encountered this notation before?  I wish to make use of it in a textbook I am writing, should I ask his permission to use this notation?

Comment: I think it's pretty common.

Comment: It's common, but usually not "extended" with lines - just listing vectors in a row or a column does the trick.

Comment: I can't see what the lines add to the notation.  The relative position of the vectors indicate whether they are row or column as I understand it.

Comment: Lines are just decoration to make the matrix look more square - personal choice of the person, but as you said, doesn't matter. The notation with vectors also makes sense if you look at a matrix as array of arrays (programmer's understanding).

Comment: @orion that makes sense.  I like the idea of assuming the matrix is square and using the lines to indicate otherwise.